# Cassandra - filtering results on a boolean

Tags: cassandra

I have a table looking like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table(
  user text,
  gender boolean,
  ...,
  PRIMARY KEY(user)
);
```

where `gender` stands for `true` for a male and `false` for a female.

I'd like to make 3 types of queries:

- 1. retrieve all the users, no matter the gender
- 2. retrieve all males
- 3. retrieve all females

I have thought of adding the `gender` parameter to the primary key. This would make queries 2 and 3 straightforward and to retrieve all users, I would need to make queries 2 and 3 and then concatenate the results.

The problem is that my user table get really big and I have to paginate the results. This poses a problem when `gender` is part of the primary key as I have to pass both `pageState` in my API response to enable the user to query for more results.

Is there a better way to enable this kind of requests making paging relatively easy and straightforward?

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "my user table get really big"? How many is big for you?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean that when a query returns quite an important number of rows I need to paginate it (I am using nodejs so I'd like to limit the memory consumption...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 questions in one.

First, the querying one. If you need these 3 types of queries then denormalize and create 3 tables: users, male_users and female_users.

Second, the paging one. If you're listing all users (or male/Female users) by querying at the table level results will be unsorted because multiple nodes will participate in elaborating the result and that partitions are hashed. If you're talking about paging at the UI level (only the first 100 users are fetched and displayed), it will be [tricky](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html). If you're talking about paging at the driver level (all users are fetched by chunks/pages), then it may be easier.